# Reading words from wordlist.txt into array list, sorting, and writing new file

Tags: java, arraylist, filereader

I can't figure this out for the life of me.

Steps:

- Create a new project in Eclipse
- Copy the provided wordlist.txt file into the Project folder
- Write a single Class named "Reverser" that performs the requested tasks:

Tasks:

- Use a java.util.Scanner to load each word in the wordlist.txt file into an ArrayList

  - Provide the Scanner a reference to a FileReader
- Report the number of words placed into the ArrayList
- Use the java.util.Collections class to reverse the order of the references in the ArrayList
- Use a java.util.Formatter to write the re-ordered words into a new text file named "reversed.txt"

  - Provide the Formatter with a reference to a FileWriter
- Make sure that each word is placed onto a separate line
- Additionally, write code so that Java provides the correct end of line terminator for each line. **Note:** No \n, or \r\n allowed!
- Write code to help ensure your program has no resource leaks.

Here is what I have so far

```
public class Reverser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = null;
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Nick\\JavaWorkspace\\Lab 7\\wordlist.txt");
        ArrayList<String> list;

        try {
            scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        list = new ArrayList<String>();

        while((scan.nextLine()) != null){
            list.add(scan.next());
        }

        String[] stringArr = list.toArray(new String[0]);

    }
}
```

Comment: What's your specific question? (other than "can you help me do my homework")

Comment: I would guess that his question is how to reverse the order of the array with the Collections class

Comment: The file path is missing a \ to escape the space in "Lab 7", should be "...JavaWorkspace\\Lab\ 7\\wordlist.txt"

8 years later, ChatGPT can write the whole thing for you now.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you general guideline to follow. 
This is a nice task to get some hands on experience in the following areas:

- Using Input to read (from a file) and Output stream to write (to a file)
- Using the `size()` method for your List object.
- Using `finally` block with your `try/catch` block to clean up resources(close scanner in finally block)
- Using `Collections.reverseOrder()` method.

You can look up those things individually and then try to integrate piece by piece in your code.